# All labels in my custom UITableViewCell are squished

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I can't seem to figure out why my UITableViewCell UILabels are all squished when I run in the simulator. Here is view of the Story View file:

[image: Story Board]

However, this is what I end up seeing in the simulator:

[image]

These are the following constraints that are applied:

[image]

I have implemented the protocol function for returning the height for a TableView row:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 65
     }
```

Lastly, when I analyze all of the UI elements in the debugger (e.g. po cell.namelabel.frame), I see that all of the frames of each of the elements make sense relative to container (both the origins and the sizes make is what I'd expect), and each element has the appropriate superview (the labels' superview is the content view, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

`SerialNumberLabel.top` constraint needs to be defined, you can use `NameLabel` as a top reference.In addition to that issue, `ValueLabel` leading reference is also missing.

Comment: Unfortunately none of those fixes fixed the issue. All of the elements (including NameLabel) look like they're fixed at (0,0) in the TableViewCell, despite all of their frames saying otherwise in the debugger, so it's almost as though none of the constraints are being read at all.